# Flutter web integration_test reuses previous browser window

Tags: flutter, firebase-authentication

I noticed that when I run integration tests for Web, Flutter driver reuses previous browser window (and session).

```
fvm flutter drive --driver=test_driver/integration_test.dart \
  --target=integration_test/app_web_integration_tests.dart \
  --web-renderer=html \
  -d chrome \
  --browser-name=chrome \
  --web-port=58565\
  --no-pub \
  --debug
```

If you just run the app using this command:

```
flutter run --web-port=58565 --web-renderer=html -d chrome
```

It always creates a fresh window, and by that I mean - it doesn't contain the previous session.

I'm having an issue, every second integration_test run my app contains a leftover Firebase session, and I can't start the emulator in the second test, because when Firebase initializes with session it won't let you do that.